# Both Quicktime Player and VLC keep stopping the video (but not the audio) since 10.6.8. Any ideas?

Tags: quicktime, vlc

Since I updated to 10.6.8 yesterday (and this might be coincidence), both Quicktime Player (I still use 7) and VLC (current version) keep stopping the video (but not the audio) of movies I am watching. This happens whether they are in the background or fullscreen and fixes itself when the program gains focus.

Is this a faulty video driver that came with 10.6.8 or what could be the reason?

Mac Pro 2009 2x2.26 GHz, 24 GB, ATI Radeon HD 4870.

Comment: This is still ongoing. And I remember that it happened before but went away again.

Comment: Yes, even for me on a fairly fast MacBook Pro 2.3GHz i5 (10.6.8) Rendering some edits in After Effects, they play perfectly fine, but once I export them, the players stutter and pause for an uncomfortable amount of time before eventually resuming.

Comment: Everything started working again a few months ago. Still don't know what it was.

Answer (score -1):

This kind of behavior, whether it is video only stopping (but audio continuing) or audio only stopping (but video continuing), has happened to me when the machine was over-loaded with other processes running. Quitting chrome, with my many open tabs, has solved the problem for me before.